# Postman api url not working after depolyment

Tags: next.js, postman, vercel

I am new to web development and recently following some tutorial and now I am facing a problem after I tried to deploy my Next App to Vercel.

One of my error happen on api url

before I deploy my app to vercel, I am using localhost3000 and the api url works fine at postman

```js
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

export const getUsers = async () => {
    // declar response and assign fetch data
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/users`)
    // declar json and assign jsoned response
    const json = await response.json()
    return json;
}
```

After I deploy my app to vercel, a new domain is provided

let newURL = "https://crud-employee-management.vercel.app/"

In my case, do I need to switch BASE_URL to newURL? But in Postman the newURL is not working like "https://crud-employee-management.vercel.app/api/users"

How could I fix it and use it at website?

Thanks

Stan

Comment: You do need to switch baseUrl to newUrl. What is the issue you get when you hit new url endpoint through postman?

Comment: my postman returns

{
    "error": "Error in the Connection"
}

It seems from the mongodb altas connection?

Comment: I think it will be better to show my github project code for your reference:

https://github.com/Stanlpm/CRUD-Employee-Management.git

Comment: What do Vercel function logs show?